# Retrieve documents from Document Library based on selections in InfoPath Form

Tags: document-library, infopath-form

I would like a user to fill out an InfoPath form and based on their input, pull the relevant documents into a view, a zip folder or just provide links to the documents. For example, if the user selects 'TimeSheet', the 'TimeSheet' document would appear for the user in a view, zip folder or a link. Please let me know if something like this can be achieved.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can create web service, which will download and zip document from input, and

- save zip to SharePoint temporary library, send link to InfoPath,
  after succesfully download, the zip file will be deleted.
- or send the whole zip to InfoPath form

This web service will be called by button in InfoPath form.

Comment: Thank you, Zdenek. Is there a way to do the reverse of the action? To submit InfoPath form and pull the relevant documents from SharePoint library?

Comment: you mean you upload zip to infopath or documents? which you want to save to defined library?

Comment: Documents currently exist in a Document Library. I would like to use an InfoPath form to pull the relevant documents. For example, user would select documents 'A' and 'B' on the InfoPath form, submit the form, and the output are documents 'A' and 'B' (can be zipped or as is).